# Resizing Images with CSS

Tags: html, css, resize

I want to have an image set in `600px` for design purposes. However, I want to reduce the height depending on the size of the screen. If I try `height: auto` this will overwrite the code of the `600px`. I have the image in a container of `800px`.

What can I do?

Comment: Try setting the height of the container as a percent of the size of the screen?

Comment: It's not clear exactly how you want your resize behavior to function based on the text of your question, but I think using media queries is a good start. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

Users correctly note that your question is very vague. If I understand you correctly, you need the picture inside the container with a width of 600 pixels to be always in the same position.

```
.image{
    position: relative;
    height: 600px;
}

.image img {
        min-width: 100%;
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%; // or width depending on aspect ratio

        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;

        object-fit: cover;

        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

to resize images by  reducing size of screen you should use width:100%  otherwise you can make a div and apply a background image on it with same image

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image to take the entire height of the container, you'd have to set the container height to 600px and then the height of the image to 100%. As per resizing based on screen size, you'd have to use media query.